# How to show result in View when search in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show the result when search a keyword successful.

In `routes\web.php`:

```
Route::get('tim-kiem', 'Frontend\ListBaiVietController@timkiemBaiViet');
```

In controller `ListBaiVietController`, I have a function:

```
public function timkiemBaiViet() {
    $tukhoa = \Request::get('tukhoa');
    $ketquatimkiems = Post::where('title','like','%'.$tukhoa.'%')
                            ->orderBy('title')
                            ->paginate(20);

    // var_dump($ketquatimkiems);
    return view('post/searchresult',compact('ketquatimkiems'));
}
```

I am using `var_dump($ketquatimkiems)`, it shows 2 results.

In `post/index.php` I am calling `content`:

```
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
```

And `post/searchresult.php`:

```
@extends('post.index')

@section('content')
    @foreach($ketquatimkiems as $ketqua) 
        <div class="container-artical">                
            <div class="list-excerpt">
                {!! $ketqua->excerpt !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <nav class="blog-pag">
        {{ $ketquatimkiems->links() }}    
    </nav>
</div>

@endsection
```

When I am typing text `quận 8`. It is only showing code, not result.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your file name must have .blade extension

```
post/searchresult.php: to post/searchresult.blade.php:
post/index.php to post/index.blade.php
```

for more information

**Blade** is the simple, yet powerful templating engine provided with Laravel. Unlike other popular PHP templating engines, Blade does not restrict you from using plain PHP code in your views. In fact, all Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified, meaning Blade adds essentially zero overhead to your application. Blade view files use the `.blade.php` file

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Comment: wow, my fault is incredible. I really don't see that. So sorry about my question. I will accept your answer on 12 minutes.

Comment: @vanloc.glad to here it helped you

Comment: @vanloc you should also add parameter in route for get request instead of using query string and add Request class in the controller which would help you get clean urls

Comment: @saurabhkamble can you add an example in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Route::get('tim-kiem/{tukhoa}', 'Frontend\ListBaiVietController@timkiemBaiViet');
In controller:
use Illuminate\Http\Request; public function timkiemBaiViet(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $tukhoa = $input['tukhoa']; 
}

Comment: @saurabhkamble it will get url `http://localhost:8000/tim-kiem?tukhoa=qu%E1%BA%ADn+8`. And show error: `NotFoundHttpException`

Comment: @vanloc when is the id adding up into url add that code in your answer !!!

Answer (score 1):

you are not using laravel blade engine. Rename view
 files like so  `index.blade.php`